# Example of a doubly degenerate Kleinian group which does not come from a mapping torus

Tags: group-theory, geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, low-dimensional-topology

Doubly degenerate Kleinian groups are discrete subgroups of $PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$ whose limit set is all of $S^2$, the boundary of $\mathbb{H}^3$.  A standard example of such a group is given as follows:

Take a closed surface $\Sigma$ of genus at least $2$ and a pseudo-Anosov map $\varphi:\Sigma\to\Sigma$ and form the mapping torus $$M_\varphi=\Sigma\times[0,1]/\langle(x,0)\sim(\varphi(x),1)\rangle,$$ which fibers over the circle.
Taking the infinite cyclic cover $N_\varphi=\Sigma\times\mathbb{R}$ and identifying $\Sigma$ with some lift of the fiber gives an isomorphism $\pi_1(\Sigma)\cong\pi_1(N_\varphi)\subset PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$.
As $N_\varphi$ has geometrically infinite ends, this is a doubly degenerate Kleinian group.
As there are lots of closed surfaces and lots of pseudo-Anosov maps, this produces many examples of such a group.

My question is what are some other constructions or standard examples of doubly degenerate Kleinian groups outside of the class given above.  I cannot seem to find other constructions than this one in the literature.

Comment: Cross-posted on math overflow http://mathoverflow.net/questions/223796/example-of-a-doubly-degenerate-surface-group-not-coming-from-a-pseudo-anosov-map/223797#223797